# How to refer to a type of the same name in a nested scope

Tags: f#

I'm trying to access a type defined in the upper-level module:

```
module MainModule

type Data = { stuff }

module XmlDeserialization =
    type Data() =
       [<XmlAttribute("stuff")>]
       member val stuff ...

       member x.ToDomainType() =
           {
               stuff = x.stuff
           } : MainModule.Data
```

The problem is, the last line doesn't compile because "the type 'MainModule' isn't defined."

I'm able to achieve what I want using namespaces instead, but is it possible to do this using modules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot reference `MainModule` within the body of `MainModule` itself, because at that point, the module is technically not defined yet. This can be reproduced with a smaller program:

```
module M =

  type T = T
  let x: T = T    // OK
  let y: M.T = T  // Error: module M is not defined yet
```

The simplest solution for you would be to finish defining `MainModule` before you start defining `XmlDeserialization`:

```
module MainModule =

    type Data = { stuff }

module XmlDeserialization =
    type Data() =
       [<XmlAttribute("stuff")>]
       member val stuff ...

       member x.ToDomainType() =
           {
               stuff = x.stuff
           } : MainModule.Data  // Works now
```

But if you insist that `XmlDeserialization` be nested under `MainModule`, *and* you insist that the types must have the same name, then you can work around the type shadowing by creating an alias of the original type before defining the overshadowing one:

```
module XmlDeserialization =

    // Alias the original type
    type MainModule_Data = Data

    type Data() =
       [<XmlAttribute("stuff")>]
       member val stuff ...

       member x.ToDomainType() =
           {
               stuff = x.stuff
           } : MainModule_Data  // Refer by alias: works now
```

Answer (score 4):

In this specific case, it should just work if you remove the type annotation. The compiler will infer the record type from the fields of the record `Data`.

In general, you can declare a function to enforce a given record type, for example:

```
let private mainModuleData (instance : Data) = instance
```

If this function is defined before `Data` gets shadowed, even if the record fields are ambiguous, you can use the function to enforce the correct type:

```
   member x.ToDomainType() =
       mainModuleData
        { stuff = x.stuff }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for mentioning it works without the type annotation! I guess it's because the inner type is a class and not a record, so here record construction syntax unambiguously refers to the outer type.

Comment: @Asik When using record construction syntax, the type is selected via field names, not type name. So even if you make more record types called `Data`, there won't be a problem as long as the types are unambiguous from their field names. BTW, for ambiguous field names, I preferred a function instead of a type alias because it doesn't mess with the type IntelliSense shows, which can cause confusion. A function that enforces the type is transparent to the user, while a private alias can contaminate mouseovers, even outside its accessible scope, in VS2015.